# Styling input field focused by keyboard

Tags: html, css, focus

I am trying to set different styling on input field which is focused by keyboard (not by mouse).

I know that it's possible to distinct focus by mouse and keyboard on other elements by using pseudo-class `:focus-visible` but it's not working on input due the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-focus-visible-pseudo):

```
The :focus-visible pseudo-class applies while an element matches the :focus pseudo-class and the UA determines via heuristics that the focus should be made evident on the element.

For example, UAs typically display focus indicators on text fields any time they’re focused, to draw attention to the fact that keyboard input will affect their contents.

On the other hand, UAs typically only display focus indicators on buttons when they were focused by a keyboard interaction (such as tabbing through the document)—because it’s not always immediately obvious where the focus has gone after such an interaction, but is sufficiently self-evident when the button was focused by more obviously-targetted interactions, like clicking on the button with a mouse pointer.
```

Is there any solution to distinct styling when **input field** is focused by mouse or keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You could add additional styles for `:hover` in addition to `:focus-visible` or `:focus` if that works for you. The example is here (https://codepen.io/alekskorovin/pen/OJxJaQB):

```css
input {
  outline: 4px dashed transparent;
}
input:focus-visible {
  outline: 4px dashed darkorange;
}
input:hover:focus-visible {
  outline: 4px dashed darkgreen;
}
input:hover {
  outline: 4px dashed transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Nice try but I need better solution which will always work. Not only when user will left mouse on input field.